# How to configure SSL Certificate to TomEE 7?

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have a configured SSL Certificate to Glassfish 4, now I want this to be configured for TomEE-7. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: I really appreciate people who down voted without pointing my mistake. Let me know, is this question correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution to this.

I have *one* **.key** and *two* **.cer** [web certificate and CA certificate] files with me.

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomee.jks -trustcacerts -file caCert.cer

keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomee.jks -file myWeb.cer
```

Then modify config/server.xml

```
<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="tomee.jks"
                        certificateKeyPassword="passwd"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Now, restart your server.

> Make sure, if you want to enable only port 9090. the server.xml file
>   should have ***one and only*** Connector tag. 
>   `<Connector port="9090"../>`

Anybody finds any error, please add comments.